# Reduce lag caused by a script in Unity 2d

Tags: c#, android, performance, unity3d-2dtools

I'm using this script to make a background scroll. The background is a material on a quad:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class scrollBG : MonoBehaviour {


     Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        MeshRenderer mr = GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ();

        Material mat = mr.material;

        Vector2 offset = mat.mainTextureOffset;

        offset.x += Time.deltaTime / 6f;

        mat.mainTextureOffset = offset; 

    }
}
```

It works fine up until about 30 seconds into gameplay then it's very laggy and gets progressively worse. The game setup is very simple, just a landscape view of planets flying from one side of the screen to the other that you have to dodge. How can I improve the lag?? (The planets move just fine). Might be worth mentioning that I'm developing for Android.

Answer (score 1):

1) I do not know what size of textures that you can do so long offset. I thought that in such cases, simply moving objects, and then change its...

2) GetComponent very long run. (mr.material too) Use caching. Try this:

```
MeshRenderer mr;
Material mat;

    void Start(){
        mr = GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ();
        mat = mr.material;
    }

    void Update () {
        Vector2 offset = mat.mainTextureOffset;

        offset.x += Time.deltaTime / 6f;

        mat.mainTextureOffset = offset; 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I just tried this, it works a little better in the game window in Unity but still the same on the Android device.

Comment: I did not like your offset. You saw this in a lesson? Are you sure this is the case the code? Have you tried to clean it up? Maybe you have chosen is incorrect videadapter during assembly the package?

Comment: I got it from YouTube yeah. What else can I do with the offset?

Comment: Try to make the moving sprites

Comment: Sprites can't be the texture for the quad? If you mean completely re-write this, any chance of a push in the right direction with some code?